# Block multiple categories from Blog

Tags: categories, blog, customization

I found this code on this site by AshFrame which I added to my functions PHP file and works perfectly to stop one category being displayed on my blog (I have a custom menu so have the category displayed separately)...

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'block_cat_query' );

function block_cat_query() {
    global $wp_query;   
    if( is_home() ) {
        $wp_query->query_vars['cat'] = '-98';
    }
}
```

My question is how do I format this code to include a second category (in my case -92)? I tried duplicating the code but it generates a PHP error because you can only run the function once I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*cat* takes a comma deliminated list, so '-98,-92'

Further reading http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters

Comment: Thank you Simon - that was straight forward (if you know what you are doing with Wordpress) ... ;-) ... really appreciate your help. Works great.

Comment: Pleasure. The codex is always my first port of call.. If I'm using a parameter I take the time to learn about the parameter fully so I can use it moot efficiently.. I only started doing this recently but found that its not actually that time consuming to have a little learning aside while working on a client project (obviously I don't bill them for that 30 seconds ha ha)