# Is it possible to restrict viewing of category PAGE to logged in users only?

Tags: categories, pages, content-restriction

I want to block the category page so that only logged in users can view the category page.  I'm not talking about the posts in the page, I'm meaning the actual page view.

For instance, if I have a post category called "support", anyone can type in "/category/support/" after the domain name and view the posts in that category, but I need to restrict it so that only logged in users can see view that category page.

How can this be done?  I don't need log in forms or anything special, just to block viewing of the category pages.  I've tried adding custom meta keys into the category template that link with the wp-members plugin I've installed, and tried some other solutions including [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/64206/block-multiple-categories-from-blog).

I can't find any plugins to do this, and no other code I've tried has worked yet.  If anyone can help, that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty answers on WPSE about restricting page views based on logged in users or visitors.

what you should do is first check if user is logged in then check if you are on your *restricted* category and redirect on another page (maybe home or login page) if user is not logged in.

something like this in your `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_restrict_support');
function wpse_restrict_support(){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_category( 'support' ) ) {
    wp_redirect( '/wp-login.php' );
    exit;
  }
}
```

check out [is_category()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/), [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) and [wp_redirect()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) for more info

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, however that's not working at the moment.  Do I need any additional plugins or to add any additional code in the template file?  I'll carry on tinkering around with this but any help would be great!    (most solutions I'm seeing work on the post meta, which category views don't have as far as I know?)

Comment: I didn't test at first, but now I did, and it's actually working for me. If support is not a custom taxonomy term (if it's in the default WP categories taxonomy) then it should be working for you too.  Test again with my edited answer

Comment: I think that works :) I will test properly and mark as resolved later if so!  Thanks!  Is it possible to use this method to disable RSS feeds too?  I'm a bit wary of using plugins.

Comment: Good. For feeds I haven't tested it but it should work the same if you use the [`is_feed()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) check. Just add another condition. Something like  `if( ! is_user_logged_in() && ( is_category( 'support' ) || is_feed() ) ) { ... }`

Comment: Yes works great!  Many thanks!  I'll give the rss one a go, see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Glad you got it working, good luck